# MySQL why does this IF() statement always return same value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a line of code which is supposed to return null output if there is no member id, and return the type of membership if it is not null.

I used outer join to join the tables, so that if the card number for that receipt is null, receipt is not associated with any membership. I used outer join membership table with lifetime membership table, so if lifetime membership id is null, it means that the member is not a lifetime member and therefore it is a plain member.

```
if
(
i.member_cardnum=null,
'null',
(if(lifetime_cardnum=null,'Plain Member','Lifetime Member'))
) as 'Member Type'
```

- If member_cardnum is null
- return null
- else
- if lifetime_cardnum is null, return 'plain member', else 'lifetime member'

I can't figure out why the code always returns 'Lifetime Member' regardless of contents of the row.

How to modify the code for it to work?

Comment: Use `IS NULL` instead of `=null`

Answer (score 1):

The expression `= null` is always going to return false.  Any comparison to `null`, except `is null` and the null-safe operators returns `null` which is interpreted as "not true" in boolean logic.

You can do this without nested `if()` statements, by using `case`:

```
(case when i.member_cardnum is null then 'null' 
      when lifetime_cardnum is null then 'Plain Member'
      else 'Lifetime Member'
 end) as "Member Type"
```

I also changed the `as` statement to use double quotes.  Only use single quotes for string constants.  Using them for identifiers is inviting confusing and problems.

Comment: Any comparison to null returns null except for `IS NULL` ... or ... `<=>` the null-safe equality comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge the `null` always evaluate false.

```
    //This line return false
    select if(null,'true','false')as returntype;
    OR    
    select if(0,'true','false')as returntype;

     //This line return true
     select if(1,'true','false')as returntype;
```

Hope it will clear your doubt.

Comment: Technically, expressions involving null do not evaluate to false... they evaluate to null, which is neither true nor false.  In rhe case of the `IF()` function, the third argument is returned when the first argument doesn't evaluate to true, which is not precisely the same thing as saying that the first argument evaluates to false.